# Using session variables in a partial rendered in realtime with ActionCable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm making a realtime chat application in Rails and I'm having trouble differentiating between the messages sent by each user. In my message partial I use the current_user session to apply either .current-user or .other-user to each message.

```
_message.html.erb

<% if msg.text.present? %>
    <% if msg.user_id == current_user.id %>
        <p class="current-user msg"><%= msg.text %></p>
    <% else %>
        <p class="other-user msg"><%= msg.text %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

New messages are broadcast from the messages controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
...    
def create
    @chat = Chat.find(params[:chat_id])
    @message = @chat.messages.build(message_params)
    if @message.save
        ActionCable.server.broadcast "chat_channel",
                                      message: render_message(@message)
    end
end
...
private
    def render_message(msg)
        render(partial: 'message', locals: { msg: msg })
    end
```

And appended to the message list with javascript

```
chats.coffee
received: (data) ->
                $('#messages').append data.message
                $('#message_text').val('')
                messages_to_bottom()
```

I've almost got it working but it looks like current_user = msg.user_id all the time. So even messages from the other user are being rendered with the current-user class. Is there any way to render these messages correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rendering the message on the client side from the chat.coffee file, first getting the user id from the message form

```
user_id = parseInt($('#message_user_id').val())
```

and then

```
received: (data) ->
                if user_id == data.user_id
                    $('#messages').append "<div class='current-user msg'>" + data.text + "</div>"
                else
                    $('#messages').append "<div class='other-user msg'>" + data.text + "</div>"
                $('#message_text').val('')
                messages_to_bottom()
```

I don't really like it because I've already written the message partial. If anyone has a better way, I'd really like to hear it.